# change element equal to pivot in quicksort

Tags: quicksort

**why is it benefic for the quicksort to change (in partition void) elements that has the same value as the pivot?**

I was asked that but I don't know why... maybe cos if they dont change, the array may stay unordered?

```
1 3 5 [3] 2 6
    i     j     swap to

1 3 2 [3] 5 6
```

and it will make any more swaps later for some reason? I dont know...

I'd like to know why swapping the elements with same value as the pivot is a good thing.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what the example you’ve included means. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this array: `int[] array = {1, 2, 4, 3, 4};`

Pivot could be `array[2] = 4`, if we choose it by calculating `(low + high) / 2`

Now, let's consider a situation we don't swap array elements when the element is equal to pivot. We'll fall into the infinite loop and get StackOverflowError.

```
private int partition(int[] array, int left, int right){
    int pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];
    while(left <= right){
        while(array[left] <= pivot) // CAUSES INFINITE LOOP. Should be array[left] < pivot
            left++;
        while(array[right] > pivot)
            right--;

        if(left <= right){
            swap(left, right, array);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    return left;
}
```

Comment: how can this `while` generate a stack overflow? sooner or later `array[left]` will satisfy the condition or just stop searching... btw the are some absent conditions in the `while` loops (something about while left is smaller than right)